# can you download viresus

Tags: malware

If i where to download a virus would it go to my host computer?

Comment: You've provided no actual specifics (*what type of file/malware; Virus is really a windows only issue subset of malware that impacts he windows OS; though some malware can impact all OSes*) including no release details. In most cases all you're downloading is a *file*... which will get stored & nothing more..  Windows tends to try and do things to aid-users (*thus why viruses are a problem there*) but in most cases on Ubuntu nothing is done. If you setup tools to act on that file automatically things may change; however in most cases nothing changes; a virus is code that needs to be run

Comment: There are malware tools for Linux and Ubuntu; they're not often used, but where they are; it's almost always to protect windows machines that are using those files (ie. the malware risk (esp. virus) isn't to the unix/linux/Ubuntu machine, but windows machines that maybe served if the system is running as a file-server for example).